# ARM DS-5 Web services unavailable

Tags: eclipse, arm, ds-5

I am trying to enter the activation code for the ARM DS-5 license in Eclipse install for Win7, but get error saying Web services unavailable, check network settings.  I have already verified I have internet connection through browser within the tool, and have verified I am not using any proxy to access the internet.  Basically, I am @ step 3 in the following ARM support link, but no paid license therefore no support..

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka16225.html

Anyone else experience this?
Evan

Below is an example error log I get from a session:

```
!SESSION 2013-07-22 16:18:34.028 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_35
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -pluginCustomization C:\Users\212058819\AppData\Roaming\ARM\DS-5\workbench\pluginCustomization.ini -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -pluginCustomization C:\Users\212058819\AppData\Roaming\ARM\DS-5\workbench\pluginCustomization.ini -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.platform.ide

!ENTRY com.arm.newsfeed 4 0 2013-07-22 16:19:07.757
!MESSAGE Error when reading RSS feed "http://forums.arm.com/index.php?/rss/blog/"
!STACK 0
java.net.UnknownHostException: forums.arm.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:227)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:317)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:174)
    at com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader.<init>(XmlReader.java:151)
    at com.arm.newsfeed.rss.AggregatedFeed.fetch(AggregatedFeed.java:226)
    at com.arm.newsfeed.rss.AggregatedFeed.access$3(AggregatedFeed.java:222)
    at com.arm.newsfeed.rss.AggregatedFeed$3.run(AggregatedFeed.java:201)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-22 16:19:13.388
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.arm.debugger.launcher2.databasewrapper.ConfigurationDatabaseWrapper", thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" timed out waiting (5007ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-7,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.arm.debugger.launcher2_5.15.0.20130620_160734 [319]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.arm.debugger.launcher2.databasewrapper.ConfigurationDatabaseWrapper" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:dropins/plugins/com.arm.debugger.launcher2_5.15.0.20130620_160734.jar" by thread "Worker-7".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.arm.debugger.launcher2.LauncherPlugin$1.run(LauncherPlugin.java:154)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 15 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.arm.debugger.launcher2.LauncherPlugin$1.run(LauncherPlugin.java:154)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

!ENTRY com.arm.eclipse.users 4 150 2013-07-22 16:20:46.074
!MESSAGE Unable to check service
!STACK 0
com.arm.webapis.client.RemoteAPIException: Unable to execute API call /api/v1/connect-test?product=ds5&version=5.15.0
    at com.arm.webapis.client.Client.doAPICall(Client.java:148)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.remote.LicenseService.checkService(LicenseService.java:157)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.obtain.ObtainLicensePage.checkService(ObtainLicensePage.java:240)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.obtain.ObtainLicensePage.setVisible(ObtainLicensePage.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1287)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.LicenseManagerDialog$6.widgetSelected(LicenseManagerDialog.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.LicenseManagerController.open(LicenseManagerController.java:86)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.OpenDialogHandler.execute(OpenDialogHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at com.arm.workbench.Hook.run(Hook.java:463)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ds.arm.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at com.arm.webapis.client.WebFileInputStream.<init>(WebFileInputStream.java:168)
    at com.arm.webapis.client.WebFileInputStream.<init>(WebFileInputStream.java:76)
    at com.arm.webapis.client.Client.doAPICall(Client.java:114)
    ... 51 more
!SESSION 2013-07-22 16:25:59.551 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_35
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -pluginCustomization C:\Users\212058819\AppData\Roaming\ARM\DS-5\workbench\pluginCustomization.ini -product org.eclipse.platform.ide
Command-line arguments:  -pluginCustomization C:\Users\212058819\AppData\Roaming\ARM\DS-5\workbench\pluginCustomization.ini -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.platform.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-07-22 16:26:28.740
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.arm.debugger.launcher2.databasewrapper.ConfigurationDatabaseWrapper", thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" timed out waiting (5007ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-5,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.arm.debugger.launcher2_5.15.0.20130620_160734 [319]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" is proceeding but "com.arm.debugger.launcher2.databasewrapper.ConfigurationDatabaseWrapper" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:dropins/plugins/com.arm.debugger.launcher2_5.15.0.20130620_160734.jar" by thread "Worker-5".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.arm.debugger.launcher2.LauncherPlugin$1.run(LauncherPlugin.java:154)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 15 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1087)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.arm.debugger.launcher2.LauncherPlugin$1.run(LauncherPlugin.java:154)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

!ENTRY com.arm.eclipse.users 4 150 2013-07-22 16:26:45.916
!MESSAGE Unable to check service
!STACK 0
com.arm.webapis.client.RemoteAPIException: Unable to execute API call /api/v1/connect-test?product=ds5&version=5.15.0
    at com.arm.webapis.client.Client.doAPICall(Client.java:148)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.remote.LicenseService.checkService(LicenseService.java:157)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.obtain.ObtainLicensePage.checkService(ObtainLicensePage.java:240)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.obtain.ObtainLicensePage.setVisible(ObtainLicensePage.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showStartingPage(WizardDialog.java:1287)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1089)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.LicenseManagerDialog$6.widgetSelected(LicenseManagerDialog.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.LicenseManagerController.open(LicenseManagerController.java:86)
    at com.arm.eclipse.licensemanager.ui.OpenDialogHandler.execute(OpenDialogHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at com.arm.workbench.Hook.run(Hook.java:463)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ds.arm.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:272)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:329)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at com.arm.webapis.client.WebFileInputStream.<init>(WebFileInputStream.java:168)
    at com.arm.webapis.client.WebFileInputStream.<init>(WebFileInputStream.java:76)
    at com.arm.webapis.client.Client.doAPICall(Client.java:114)
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: Could you post the exact error you're getting? Seeing a traceback or error code could be invaluable in debugging this.

Comment: Just uploaded an example error file I get..

Answer (score 4):

It seems for some reason that your eclipse is unable to see the internet. DS-5 is also having trouble seeing other internet sites according to the log you posted (forums.arm.com). So I suspect you have a problem talking to the internet.

I've seen problems like these caused by the proxy settings in eclipse. Can you check proxy settings? These can be found my opening the preferences from the menu "Window -> Preferences". Now look at the settings in "General -> Network Connections".

If you don't need a proxy, can you make sure all of the entries in this dialog are disabled. Also switch the "Active Provider" to "Native".

Sometimes people have only got HTTP proxy setup, HTTPS is needed for DS-5 web services.